# Running flutter doctor -v shows errors

Tags: flutter

This is what I'm getting after running the command in the title:

```
Authentication error (403)
package:pub/src/authentication/client.dart 95:5    _AuthenticatedClient._throwAuthException
package:pub/src/authentication/client.dart 60:9    _AuthenticatedClient.send
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/authentication/client.dart 133:12  withAuthenticatedClient
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 862:22          HostedSource._download.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/io.dart 886:12                     withTempDir
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 859:5           HostedSource._download
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 669:7           HostedSource.downloadToSystemCache
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/result.dart 86:9            SolveResult.downloadCachedPackages.<fn>.<fn>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? flutter sdk is there.

Comment: may be your your ip address is block. try with vpn.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solve it error by configuring Flutter to use a mirror site, because the official URL (https://storage.googleapis.com) from where *flutter doctor* downloads some needed packages is blocked for my country, even using VPN doesn't establish the connection.

So, to do that, I set two environment variables, *PUB_HOSTED_URL* and *FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL*, with a server mirror for Flutter dependencies and packages, as described at https://docs.flutter.dev/community/china.

Run the following commands:

**In Linux:**

```
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn

export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

**In Windows:**

```
set PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn

set FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

After these steps, you should be able to continue setting up Flutter normally.